# How to view/Open dropbox file

Tags: dropbox, android-intent

I am developing and android app, where i want to get all files from drop box. Now i can retrieve all files from drop box and display it in List View. Now i want to open/display the file when i click on the List View. I don't know how to open Dropbox file, with which manager or which method??? please help

**I was using this method to open/display Google Drive file, but i don't know how to use the same method here for Dropbox.**

```
   String ur = "https://docs.google.com/file/d/"+fileID;
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(ur));
    startActivity(i);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open/view/display Dropbox files of any extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083547/how-to-open-view-display-dropbox-files-of-any-extension)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible.

[I posted in their forums and got a negative response](https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=121360). Hopefully it'll be functionality they look to support soon.